# Tengo problemas con "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: tkinter, pycharm

Amigos, tengo un pequeño problema con Pycharm, el cual al intentar correr este código me salta con el problema de que hay un error, el cual está en el titulo, ¿A*lguien sabe que debo corregir*? Saludos!

```
from tkinter import *

def ventana():
    global ventana
    global caja1

    ventana=Tk()
    ventana.title("Ventana 1")
    ventana.geometry("900x600+100+20")
    ventana.config(bg="red")
    n1=IntVar()
    caja1=Entry(ventana,textvariable=n1,width=30)
    caja1.place(x=340, y=360)
    boton=Button(ventana,text="VENTANA 2",width=10,height=3,command=ventana_2)
    boton.place(x=400, y=430)
    ventana.mainloop()

def ventana_2():
    global window
    global caja2

    clave=float(caja1.get())
    bd=123
    if (clave==bd):
        ventana.withdraw()
        window=Toplevel()
        window.title("Ventana 2")
        window.geometry("900x400+300+100")
        window.config(bg="blue")
    else:
    mensaje="CLAVE INCORRECTA"
    caja1.insert(0,mensaje)

ventana_1()
```

Segun mi perspectiva no debería haber error ya que están todos los if y demases separados como corresponde, ¿O hay algo que deba arreglar? Perdon por la ignorancia, soy nuevo en programación.

Comment: Python es delicado con la identacion verifica que tú código esté bien identado que sean tabs en vez de espacio puedes observar el else de clave incorrecta que está mal identado

Comment: Acabo de reescribir el mismo código viendo que nada se haya corrido con espacio sino que con tabulador y aún así me sigue saltando el mismo error @JackNavaRow

Comment: Debes entender que cuatro espacios no es lo mismo que una tabulación. Ademá el contenido del `else` del final está mal indentado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era la identación  casi al final de tu código, exactamente después del `else:` y el otro problema era que la función a la que llamabas no existía, me refiero a `ventana_1()`, aquí te paso el código corregido:

```
from tkinter import *


def ventana():
    global ventana
    global caja1

    ventana=Tk()
    ventana.title("Ventana 1")
    ventana.geometry("900x600+100+20")
    ventana.config(bg="red")
    n1=IntVar()
    caja1=Entry(ventana,textvariable=n1,width=30)
    caja1.place(x=340, y=360)
    boton=Button(ventana,text="VENTANA 2",width=10,height=3,command=ventana_2)
    boton.place(x=400, y=430)
    ventana.mainloop()

def ventana_2():
    global window
    global caja2

    clave=float(caja1.get())
    bd=123
    if (clave==bd):
        ventana.withdraw()
        window=Toplevel()
        window.title("Ventana 2")
        window.geometry("900x400+300+100")
        window.config(bg="blue")
    else:
        mensaje="CLAVE INCORRECTA"
        caja1.insert(0,mensaje)

ventana()
```